# How to draw a curved line in Pixlr

Tags: pixlr

I am very new to Graphic Design and I am trying to create a curved line on Pixlr.

I click on the Draw Tool, I click on the line but the only option is to draw a straight line.

How can I create a curved line, like that of a rainbow, in Pixlr?

Answer (score 3):

There's not a good curve tool in Pixlr that makes easy to control curves.

But for the rainbow you can draw a series of circles that overlap. The next is smaller than the previous.

The order: Red, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet. The last one is a piece of sky. Erase the bottom half.

ADDENDUM: I tried it. A tedious job, took a long time due the lack of the control.

[image]

If you have to add a rainbow into an outdoor landscape photo, this way is totally useless. Your only option to create it is to paint it by free hand using a small, transparent brush one color at a time. To do it properly you must have a good graphic tablet. Your eyes and hands must have pro quality steadiness and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to "manually" make a rainbow, you need to use colored ovals layered one on top of the other... its still a tedious task but much better than hand-drawing elipses.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/112268)

Answer (score 0):

what i do is create an oval on outline and then erase part of it to leave a curved line